# How can I copy paste a list a very long Facebook search result list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So here is something that I was stuck on for the past week.

My task is to get a list of fans of a Facebook page - at the end, in a .txt format.

Although the Facebook API doesn't share fans of a Facebook page that isn't yours, this information is publicly available when you search "People who like ________" in the search bar.

For example: https://www.facebook.com/search/1708921982760465/likers

The problem is that there are many likers, thousands - however this webpage list only shows 10, then you need to scroll down to load 10 more, and so-on. Not only would scrolling down for 10,000 likers be very time-consuming, but I believer it would be quite impossible to load such a long page in my browser without it crashing.

My first way of solving this problem was to load keep scrolling and then copy paste the list. This method didn't work because my computer froze mid-way.

Are there any alternative methods to getting this list? such as perhaps loading some text only html version of the page that won't crash the browser? Or maybe some script that would be able to send requests to obtain all the likers?

Plz help.

Comment: Just because you can see something on Facebook.com doesn't mean you can scrape it. Facebook have specific rules about scraping https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: _“My task is to get a list of fans of a Facebook page - at the end, in a .txt format”_ – what for? You would not be allowed to f.e. contact people just because they liked your page - so what’s such a list supposed to be good for anyway?

Comment: @WizKid, but is there some untraditional way to do this? not scraping but copy+paste. The main problem here is that I physically can't load such a huge page in chrome - but is there a way to remove all visual effects to make it less weight on the system?

Comment: @CBroe, I'm interested in the "how" not the "why". Thanks though.

Comment: No there is no way to do it.